# Android thread sometimes does not start

Tags: android, multithreading, thread-synchronization

I must use Thread in an Android project. Sometimes, it works corectly, however sometimes does not; it does not start (does not call SendToServer() method)or it starts but return to another function suddenly (return updated; line)before the thread does not finish.

Note: affected value is bigger than 0, it gives condition and it goes to if statement.

Here is the my code sample;

```
public static Boolean MyUpdateFunction(MyObject myobject){

Boolean updated=false;
//Code for updating local database


int affected= SqliteDb.update(....);

if(affected>0)
{
    //Send updated data to server
    //For this I must use Thread(I can't use AsyncThread)
    updated=true;
    SendToServer();

}


return updated;
}

public static void SendToServer()

{
    try{
        ;
        Thread th=new Thread(new Runnable() {

        public void run() {
            try {

                //Create data and send it to server
                //.......
            } catch (Exception e) {
                // TODO Auto-generated catch block
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
        }
    });
    th.start();
    th.join();




}
catch(SQLException e)
{
    Toast.makeText(myContext,"ERROR: "+e.getMessage(), Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
} catch (InterruptedException e) {
    // TODO Auto-generated catch block
    e.printStackTrace();
}
}
```

Comment: You could also use an AsyncTask, its provided by the Android SDK for background tasks.

Comment: `th.start(); th.join();` - why use a thread at all?

Comment: I couldn't use AsyncTaks because some reason. I use a library which generates proxy classes, and it does not support AsyncTask, so I must use Thread

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Instead of using threads and your variables (updated and affected), you can use AsyncTasks: see: http://developer.android.com/reference/android/os/AsyncTask.html

With AsyncTask, you have some methods which are doing exactly what you want:

- onPreExecute
- doInBackground
- onPostExecute

So, what you can do is to check your condition in onPreExecute, then do your SendToServer in the doInBackground and onPostExecute do what you need.

Comment: Thanks for your reply, but I couldn't use AsyncTask,I must use Thread because of my proxy class generetor(it does not support async)

Comment: Which proxy class generator are you using? Could you give us more details please?

Comment: I also used this one once, but have no problems geting my data in an async task...

Answer (score 1):

Other people are correct in that an AsyncTask is the way forward, but the direct problem due to what you're experiencing is this (and as such, I would recommend reading up on how Threading works):

When you start the thread, it begins a new process. The UI thread (which is generally where the majority of your code is) continues. So your code **will** fire the thread with `SendToServer()`, and then by definition will immediately `return updated`, as the UI thread immediately goes to the next line.

What you need is a callback from your Thread, which is handled in the `onPostExecute()` method of an AsyncTask. There's a good tutorial on how to use them and what they do [here](http://androidresearch.wordpress.com/2012/03/17/understanding-asynctask-once-and-forever/)

**Edit:**
I've just seen from a comment above that you can't use Asynctasks, fair enough, but you still need a callback/event fired from your Thread to return any results